# Is the redistribution default-metric value when used over vPC peer link based on port channel aggregated bandwidth or individual physical Interface?

Tags: routing, redistribution

The question is in the title. Looking at a config where they were trying to Peering traffic over an SVI, but they have the physical interfaces bandwidth listed as the value and I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

VPC isn't really relevant here.  All SVI's (whether mapped to a VPC peer link, some other random trunk or just a bunch of access ports) end up with the same bandwidth value by default.  You can adjust it manually or, indeed, you can set the derived value your IGP uses (...if applicable) but there is no automatic correlation between the underlying physical link and the value assigned.

Comment: I believe you have completely missed my question. When the ports are aggregated in a Port Channel, they have a collective bandwidth amount of all the links. But at the same time based upon configuration, the port channel can load balance the load across the links. So there is a chance that the sole interface may be used to send the traffic and not the port channel aggregated bandwidth. Since EIGRP is asking for Bandwith, it's asking what the bandwidth is for the interfaces it will be advertising over to calculate the metric.

Comment: I think you actually missed my answer.  The fact that an SVI is mapped to a port channel is immaterial to the default bandwidth NXOS assigns.  An SVI is a software construct and is assigned the same nominal value regardless of the path taken (or, indeed, number of live links).  You can manually adjust this (...which EIGRP will take into account in its minimum bandwidth calculation) or, for greater effect, tweak the delay metric.